# How do i draw vectors in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i have the following code:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewScreen(){
    val vector = ImageVector.Builder(
        defaultWidth = 100.dp,
        defaultHeight = 100.dp,
        viewportWidth = 10f,
        viewportHeight = 10f,
        tintBlendMode = BlendMode.SrcOver
    ).path(fill = Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue))) {
        moveTo(1f,1f)
        lineTo(8f, 8f)
    }.build()

    val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        with(painter){
            draw(painter.intrinsicSize)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see a gradient line. But for some reason nothing gets drawn:

[image]

**Why? What do i do wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding more lines. You use the fill param, which fills a figure with a gradient. The gradient doesn't work as well because the end point is set to infinity. Set endX and see blue color

```
val vector = ImageVector.Builder(
    defaultWidth = 100.dp,
    defaultHeight = 100.dp,
    viewportWidth = 10f,
    viewportHeight = 10f,
    tintBlendMode = BlendMode.SrcOver
).path(fill = Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue), endX = 8f)) {
    moveTo(0f, 0f)
    lineTo(0f, 8f)
    lineTo(8f, 8f)
    lineTo(8f, 0f)
    lineTo(0f, 0f)
}.build()

val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    with(painter) {
        draw(painter.intrinsicSize)
    }
}
```

If you want draw line you should use path with SolidColor like this

```
path(stroke = SolidColor(Color.Black)) {         
    moveTo(0f, 0f)         
    lineTo(0f, 6f)         
    lineTo(6f, 6f)         
    lineTo(6f, 0f)         
    lineTo(0f, 0f)     
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Using multiple `lineTo` methods i really can draw shapes. But first how can i draw just a line and second why doesn't gradient work ? Instead of it i see just the first color specified in the `listOf` function

Comment: 1. If you want draw line you should use path with SolidColor like this `path(stroke = SolidColor(Color.Black)) {
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        lineTo(0f, 6f)
        lineTo(6f, 6f)
        lineTo(6f, 0f)
        lineTo(0f, 0f)
    }`
2. The gradient doesn't work as well as the endpoint set to infinity. Set endX and see blue color. For example: `path(fill = Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue), endX = 8f))`

Comment: Thank you very much. you can add your comment to the answer so that i can mark it as right.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewScreen() {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val gradient = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue))
        drawLine(
            brush = gradient,
            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f), 
            end = Offset(x = size.width, y = size.height), 
            strokeWidth = 5.dp.toPx() 
        )
    }
}
```

[image]